# How to split Excel File into Multiple sheets?

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

Friends,
 I am new to Apache POI. I have been assigned a task of Splitting a Excel file(WorkBook) into Multiple Sheets depending on the data which are at Excel file. My Quest is,

Is it possible to split a Single Excel sheet  into multiple Excel sheets? How to Input a Excel sheet to Apache POI? so far i have practiced to create a Excel file through Apache POI and no idea about how to input a Excel sheet to Apache POI.

Any sort of HELP will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update the post with your effort or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Tutorial](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/CalendarDemo.java) will help you out to create Sheets in Excel File with Apache POI

Although the Solution is Very simple.

Tutorial Code Walk through for your help!

```
public class CalendarDemo {

    private static final String[] days = {
            "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    private static final String[]  months = {
            "January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June","July", "August",
            "September","October", "November", "December"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        boolean xlsx = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if(args[i].charAt(0) == '-'){
                xlsx = args[i].equals("-xlsx");
            } else {
              calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
            }
        }
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        //Step #01 Creating Excel WorkBook
        Workbook wb = xlsx ? new XSSFWorkbook() : new HSSFWorkbook();

        Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(wb);

        for (int month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            //create a sheet for each month

            //Step #02  Creating WorkSheets in WorkBook
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet(months[month]);
```

[image]

Comment: @Java_User Np Dude Keep Exploring